# how to fix type-punned pointer warning

Tags: c++, type-conversion, reinterpret-cast, type-punning

I have the following: (HalfType = 32bit, Type = 64bit)

```
inline static HalfType getGroupNr(const Type & id){
    Type id2 = id;
    id2 >>= sizeof(HalfType)*8;
    HalfType a = reinterpret_cast<HalfType &>(id2);
    return a;
};
```

This should extract the last 32bit of a 64bit input `id` and return these 32bit.

How do I fix this warning:

```
dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
```

And what is the exact problem in the above code and would be using a union for the `id` type be any better? (How?)

Comment: Does the warning come from the ``inline`` keyword?

Comment: According to you, which are "last 32 bit"? You're right shifting by half the size of `id`, then taking the left half. You don't know the value of those bits anymore (if `Type` is unsigned, it's all zeroes, and sign extended if it's signed, usualy).

Comment: And no, the warning is not because of `inline`.